# Как в Angular можно добавить тег при наведении?

Tags: angular2

Допустим, у меня список генерится через ngFor и нужно, что бы при наведении курсора на какой-либо объект ему добавлял класс, а после убирания курсора удалялся.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Найдите или напишите директиву для этого. Наверняка существует какой-нибудь ngHover

Comment: Илюха, такие директиві пишутся во всех гайдах по angular, на том же metanit :D

Comment: @overthesanity, да я думал, что чего-нибудь из коробки есть...

Comment: Из коробки есть [ngMouseEnter](http://docs.ng.sxisa.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter) и [ngMouseLeave](http://docs.ng.sxisa.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave)

Comment: @iluxa1810 https://metanit.com/web/angular2/3.3.php

Comment: @overthesanity, а класс добавлять элементу нужно через Renderer2.addClass ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ві задаете риторические вопросі :D

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вот такую директиву сделал:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAddClassOnHover]'
})
export class AddClassOnHoverDirective {
  @Input('appAddClassOnHover')
  className: string
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render2: Renderer2) { }
  @HostListener('mouseover') onMouseEnter() {
    this.render2.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, this.className);
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.render2.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, this.className);
  }
```

}

Comment: просто `renderer` назівайте вместо `render2`, и `ElementRef` - дженерик, можно перегрузить тип и указать что директива биндится к дом єлементам `private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>`

Comment: @overthesanity есть вопрос небольшой: Я видел, что можно передавать несколько параметров в директиву и перечислять их друг за другом в html-элементе. Так вот, а что будет если между разными директивами что-то пересечется? Или Ангулар считает, что все что до следующией директиве идет в первую директиву, а все что после во вторую?

Comment: ......не понял?

Comment: @overthesanity Сценарий, есть 2 директивы, которым можно сконфигурировать через несколько input'ов. У этих директив есть пересечения по именам. Что будет если одновременно задать эти 2 директивы для одного элемента? Сможет ли ангуляр понять какой директиве соответствует какой параметр?

Comment: ne smojet. Esli est' 2 directivy - `highlight`&`dumb` c odinakovim bindingom `testBinding` i bind9tsya oni kak `<div highlight dumb testBinding="qwe">...</div>` - to Angular zabindit svoystva 2x directiv. sorry za engl, dolbanniy linux

Comment: @overthesanity даже если после каждой дерективы указать по testBinding ? Т.е разрулить это незя никак явно?

Comment: нет, но я тебе скажу за 5 лет я ни разу не сталкивался с тем, чтобы именовал свойства одинаково, поэтому мой совет тебе - не зацикливаться на этом, а изучать что-то дальше